# how to have to insert in a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

```
 drop trigger if exists testtTrigger;

    CREATE TRIGGER testtTrigger after INSERT ON temp
      FOR EACH ROW 
        INSERT INTO author 
        (AuthorID, AuthorFname, AuthorLname) values (new.aID, new.afname, new.alname) 

        INSERT INTO book 
        (`Book ID`, book_Title) values (new.bID, new.btitle);
```

//also I 've been told to run this code in stored proceduer, however when i run it in stored procedure it runs without any problem,  but it doesn't make the triger for me, simply doesn't do the job for me the stored procedure code is bellow

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER testtTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON temp
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO author (AuthorID, AuthorFname, AuthorLname) values (new.aID, new.afname, new.alname);
    INSERT INTO book (`Book ID`, book_Title) values (new.bID, new.btitle);
  END;
```

Comment: Is your temp table a temporary table?I dont think you can create triggers on temporary tables.

Comment: I have named as temp means "temporary" but actually the table is exist all the time and its not temporary, I just named temp in order to differentiate with the actual tables that i need them

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I am using mysql server 5.6

Comment: this my first time that i am asking in stack overflow, sorry for and error and inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop trigger if exists testtTrigger;

DELIMITER //   
CREATE TRIGGER testtTrigger after INSERT ON temp
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO author(AuthorID, AuthorFname, AuthorLname) values (new.aID, new.afname, new.alname); 
    INSERT INTO book 
    (`Book ID`, book_Title) values (new.bID, new.btitle);
  END; //
  DELIMITER;
```

As an aside this should be done with foreign keys and `CASCADE` option.

Comment: how can I do that by using foreign keys and CASCADE option. because its already many to many relationship its like ((author) (book), (author_Book), (temp) ) simply i want to become like that: when i filled the temp table, the database automatically fill other tables for me. thank you for your response